# Javascript, issues reading CSV file (original file is JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I am learning JS and I'm having an issue.

I have a sample data set: miserables.js that its in this format:

```
var miserables = {

  nodes:[
    {nodeName:"Myriel", group:1},
    {nodeName:"Napoleon", group:1},
    .....
    {nodeName:"Mme. Hucheloup", group:8}
  ],

  links:[
    {source:1, target:0, value:1},
    {source:2, target:0, value:8},
    .....
    {source:76, target:58, value:1}
  ]
};
```

and I'm reading it, just with this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./miserables.js"></script>
```

and it works perfect.

The issue comes when I want to read directly that information from two csv files:

links1.csv

```
source           target           weight     
Myriel           Napoleon            3
Napoleon         Mme. Hucheloup      2
Napoleon         Myriel             23
Mme. Hucheloup   Myriel              4 
...              ...               ...
```

nodes2.csv

```
node              group      description
Myriel              A         family A
Napoleon            C         family B
Mme. Hucheloup      C         family C
...                ...          ...
```

The script that I'm using to do so its as follows, which I can make it work:

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {

    var links = [], nodes = [], links_backup = [];

    d3.csv('./links1.csv',function(links_csv) {
      return {
        source:links_csv.source,
        target:links_csv.target,
        strength:links_csv.strength,
        year:links_csv.year,
        type:links_csv.type,
      }
    },function(csv_data) {
      $.each(csv_data,function (idx,row) {
        links.push(row)
        links_backup.push(row)
      })
    });

    d3.csv('./nodes2.csv',function (nodes_csv) {
      var row = {
        node:nodes_csv.node,
        group:nodes_csv.group,
        description_n4:nodes_csv.description_n4,
      }

      if (nodes_csv.hasOwnProperty('weight')) {
        row.weight = nodes_csv.weight
      }

      return row
    },function (data) {
        var node_groups = {}

        $.each(data,function (idx,row) {
          nodes.push(row)

          if (!node_groups.hasOwnProperty(row.group)) {
            node_groups[row.group] = {
              fill: getRandomColor()
            }
          }
        })
       })
```

Comment: "The issue comes when I want to read directly that information from two csv files". So... what is the issue? An error message? something else?

Comment: Strictly speaking those are not CSV files. They are column oriented files. Also since JavaScript does not parse CSV natively, what parser are you using? ie where does the variable `d3` come from?

Comment: sorry, I just wrote my CSV file by columns. The original are comma separated. The d3.js I downloading from https://d3js.org. @markbernard

Comment: @BrianGlaz, the issue is that my code is not reading the csv. I want to get the outcome of my code (for reading the csv), similar as I will get when I run miserables.js. Does it make sense?